# How to yield every alternate element from generator?

Tags: python

How do I yield every alternate element from a generator?

The obvious method doesn't seem to work:

```
>>> generator[::2]
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

Sure you could write code that achieves the same purpose:

```
x = 0
for item in generator:
    if x % 2 == 0:
        do_something(item)
    x += 1
```

But Python is bad at math in tight loops like this one and I'm eager to find how this could be done better.

Comment: `Python is bad at math in tight loops` - could you explain that a bit?  `could be done better.` - better how?

Comment: Look at [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). You can do `islice(<your generator>, 0, None, 2)` for example.

Comment: When you write your own generator you have complete control over which values are yielded, so I do not see what is the problem you are facing here

Comment: What do you mean by "done better"?

Comment: Strongly recommend `islice` but you could also consume one element from the generator inside the loop like so: `_ = next(generator)`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi You don't need to bother assigning the return value. `while True: next(generator); yield next(generator)`.

Comment: @chepner I thought so too, but [my quick test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwhDS.png) seemed to [indicate otherwise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnLEE.png). I realize now it's prob because it was an interactive terminal :-/

Answer (score 2):

This kind of approach can be used to deliver only those values following any kind of repetitive index pattern:

```
def yield_every_other(g):
    from itertools import compress, cycle
    return compress(g, cycle([True, False]))
```

Then, e.g.,

```
>>> for x in yield_every_other(2*i for i in range(20)):
...     print(x)
```

displays

```
0
4
8
12
16
20
24
28
32
36
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to make the second option cleaner:

```
for i, item in enumerate(generator):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        do_something(item)
```